# Website show 404 error when there is zero in the link

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I have a web address that looks like this: `https://domain.tld/sign-up/123456`

123456 is referral number, in background address works like: `https://domain.tld/sign-up.php?ref=123456`

Below I attach a .htaccess file to better understand the problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

php_flag display_errors on
php_flag display_startup_errors on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^sign-up$ /sign-up.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sign-up/([1-9]+)$ /sign-up.php?ref=$1 [L]

#if page not exist, redirect to 404 page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.php [L]
```

Until I have zero in the link, everything works as it should. But as soon as a partner has a number of 540687, then the website show me 404 error. The zero must not be anywhere. Do you wonder how I can solve this? Partner numbers can be resolved without zeros, but numbers of external wallet transactions are not. Thank you

Comment: `[1-9]+` should be `[0-9]+`

Comment: Big thanks. You are my hero. Working.